# I noticed I am missing a lot of units in Supreme Commander 1

Tags: supreme-commander

A lot of the tutorials make reference to, for example, the [UEF T3 Heavy Point Defense](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/UEF_T3_Heavy_Point_Defense) and the [UEF T3 Mobile Missile Platform](http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/UEF_T3_Mobile_Missile_Platform). However, I do not have them in my version of the game. Was this patched in later, or is it in Forged Alliance/Supreme Commander 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a "stand alone expansion," Forged Alliance, introducing new faction specific units & structures, as well as a fourth playable faction.

The UEF T3 point defense was introduced in that expansion.

Comment: it did occur to me this might be the case, but none of the sites I visited explicitly stated this.

Comment: @puk The wiki you link has a category: Forged Alliance Units. It's easy to miss if you don't know to look for it.